# Security of a free public VPN service

Tags: networking, vpn

I just started using VPNBOOK, which is a (very efficent) free VPN solution.

I have a question:

VPNBOOK user and pass used to connect to their vpn network are publicily available on their homepage; everybody uses them to connect to the vpn.

Can a user intercept my wifi traffic and:

1. Understand that my connections are directed to VPNBOOK servers.
2. If point 1 is successful, then they could use VPNBOOK public user and pass to
      decrypt my traffic?

I hope I am missing something, otherwise it would be a very big weakness and I would revert to a paid service (with a private account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a vpn of any description it is simple to see that your traffic is encrypted and traveling over a single port to a single destination. No local wireless hacker can decrypt this connection without the key that was negotiated at the time of connection in a secure way.

I find these free services very suspicious as they do have unencrypted access to all of your traffic. I would not personally use one regardless of the promises they make on their website.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if username/password is available to the public as it's only used for authentication and it's not used for encryption. On the other hand it's possible to modify OpenVPN or any other VPN software to sniff network traffic, so if you're really paranoid and/or need a real privacy you should probably buy a VPS and setup OpenVPN yourself.

Comment: Although you'd have to put that VPS somewhere that none of the 'bad people' you're hiding from can get to.